# Adding Items with same ids together in Local Storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am working on creating an add to cart option in local storage to send to our ESP for cart abandonment. I have the items once added to the cart storing in Local Storage under the key: cart. The cart creates an array and each time a product is added a new object is inserted into the array. What I am trying to figure out now is, when an item with the same sku is added again, how to I get it to update the object that is already there instead of inserting another object into the array.

```
// Try to retreive the count of shopping cart items from localStorage
var cartCounter = localStorage.getItem('cartCounter');

if (cartCounter != null) {
  // We already have at least one item in localStorage so increment the counter
  cartCounter = parseInt(cartCounter) + 1
}
else {
  // No items in localStorage so initialize the counter
  cartCounter = 1;
}

// Get the data layer push
var pr = {{DL - Add To Cart}};

// Store product sku, name, and price in localStorage
// Using string format product[cartCounter]attribute for the key
localStorage.setItem('product' + cartCounter + 'sku', pr.fullProductSKU);
localStorage.setItem('product' + cartCounter + 'name', pr.name);
localStorage.setItem('product' + cartCounter + 'price', pr.price);
localStorage.setItem('product' + cartCounter + 'quantity', pr.quantity);

var addItem = function (sku, qty, price) {
    var oldItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')) || [];        
    var newItem = {
        'product-sku': sku,
        'product-qty': qty,
        'product-price': price
    };        
    oldItems.push(newItem);        
    localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(oldItems));
};

console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')));
addItem(pr.fullProductSKU, pr.quantity, pr.price);
```

Here is the output I get which is great but the first two items have the same SKU so I want the to be combined into 1 object with qty showing 2 and price to be updated as well.

```
[{product-sku: "965000070", product-qty: 1, product-price: 40.99}
 {product-sku: "965000070", product-qty: 1, product-price: 40.99}
 {product-sku: "965000244", product-qty: 1, product-price: 48.99}]
```

Here is what I would the output to be:

```
[{product-sku: "965000070", product-qty: 2, product-price: 81.98}
 {product-sku: "965000244", product-qty: 1, product-price: 48.99}]
```

Comment: *"price to be updated as well"*: but is the SKU is the same, should the price remain the same? Or do you want the price to be the total price for that product and not the unit price?

Comment: I would like the price to update to the total price so in my example above I would like to see:
 0: {product-sku: "965000070", product-qty: 2, product-price: 81.98}
 1: {product-sku: "965000244", product-qty: 1, product-price: 48.99}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just look in the array retrieved from `cart`, and check if the product is already included, and then update the quantity. For instance, `find` can be used for that look-up:

```
var addItem = function (sku, qty, price) {
    var oldItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')) || [];
    var match = oldItems.find(function (item) {
        return item['product-sku'] === sku;
    });
    if (match) {
        match['product-qty'] += qty;
        match['product-price'] += price;
    } else {
        var newItem = {
            'product-sku': sku,
            'product-qty': qty,
            'product-price': price
        };
        oldItems.push(newItem);
    }
    localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(oldItems));
};
```

Comment: I am using GTM to insert the JS so I am not able to use => because I get an ECMASCRIPT6 error. On a side not I really appreciate the help. This is my first time working so in-depth with local storage so I have spent WEEKS just building to code above.

Comment: Removed the `=>`.

Comment: THANK YOU. 1000x THANK YOU!